# Facebook: Security error, There are problems with the security certificate for this site

Tags: android, facebook

Some users get this error when viewing the link in the Android Facebook Browser. Our SSL is current and active. And it does not happen on desktop browsers or in the ios Facebook App.

[image]

Comment: answer can be found on similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31530265/facebook-android-security-error-there-are-problems-with-the-security-certific

Answer (score 0):

This could be possibly two things:

1. Certificate on your site is invalid, or maybe chain is broken somewhere as in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31530265/facebook-android-security-error-there-are-problems-with-the-security-certific) case. You can use [SSL Labs Server Test](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html) to analyze your domain/SSL certificate.
2. Settings in the Android phone for some reason are not trusting to the issuer (root) of the certificate. On this [link](http://www.androidtablets.net/threads/solved-security-certificate-problem.56833/), they say:

> Settings -> Security -> Trusted Credentials -- Make sure they are enabled with the green checkmark. I enabled them all (possible you may only need VeriSign Inc and such enabled) but I enabled them all --- and that fixed it for me

Answer (score 0):

The same error occured on my site and the problem was that my server was not serving the Intermediate/chain certificate. Normally, modern browsers can resolve the intermediate certificate by themselves so it is optional. But some problematic browsers (like those embedded in facebook or instagram app) give this error.

You can checkout this comodo documentation to install the complete chain of your certificate:

https://support.comodo.com/index.php?/comodo/Knowledgebase/Article/View/637/37/certificate-installation-apache--mod_ssl

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely due to the embedded browser not being able to see the whole certificate chain.

You can easily fix this if you have the intermediate cert, you just need to cat it with the ssl cert Ex:

`cat IntermediateCA.cer >> ssl_certificate.cer`

Then replace the old ssl_certificate.cer with the new certificate containing the concatenated values.

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue on a website. Took some time for me to figure it out.

Please check in code if you are trying to access a url or asset file via https:// scheme and the ssl is not working on that domain.

In my particular case, www.{domain}.com was showing this error because some  tags had src from old "cdn" subdomain (https://q.{domain}.com)  and this subdomain's ssl was *not* working.

it had nothing to do with site's url or www version of site.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem with Instagram and Chrome on Android.
I used SSL Let's encrypt - first I deleted all the certificates - and changed the **SSL/TLS KEY TYPE** from **SSL/TLS** in **cPanel** from - **ECDSA, P-384** to **RSA, 2,048-bit** -you can manual generate new key or Auto install SLL and works fine