# Facebook Android: "Security Error: There are problems with the security certificate for this site"

Tags: android, facebook, security, ssl, hyperlink

I am getting the following error when trying to follow a link posted on facebook:

*"Security Error: There are problems with the security certificate for this site"*

The site has a valid SSL and the link works correctly in all browsers + iOS but not on Android. I really can't find much information about this issue at all.

Any help or insight would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hi, Please provide a code of the linking

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Facebook: Security error, There are problems with the security certificate for this site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29459942/facebook-security-error-there-are-problems-with-the-security-certificate-for-t)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

www.espressorium.com.au does not provide the complete certificate chain. See the [SSL Labs report](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=espressorium.com.au) for this site which indicates missing intermediate certs (the ones marked "Extra download").

The website needs to provide its intermediate certificates to avoid seeing this error. See https://serverfault.com/questions/620544/why-does-android-chrome-say-my-sites-security-certificate-is-not-trusted for steps to do this.

[image: SSL Labs report showing missing intermediate certificates]

Similar report from [SSL Shopper](https://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-checker.html#hostname=https://www.espressorium.com.au).

[image: SSL Shopper report showing incomplete certificate chain]

Comment: Awesome, thank you. I was able to contact the SSL provider who fixed the break in the chain. Thanks again.