# SSL Certificate error on instagram external link

Tags: android, security, ssl, ssl-certificate, instagram

I have an e-commerce website (https://gigole-store.com) using the *Let's Encrypt* Certificate.

Everything seems fine out of when i'm linking my products on instagram like on this post: https://www.instagram.com/p/BkCe4kanNTr/?taken-by=gigole_store

When from the **Instagram android app** you go thru the discover more link on the product that breing the user to the product page on the website i get an alert sayng:

**Security Error**
*There are problems with the security certificate of this website*

On the iOs app everything works fine.
Due to this issue the client is loosing all the customers coming from IG marketing campains on android.
I can't find no one on-line reporting a similar issue... i'm desperate!
Thanks for the help.

[image: This is the screenshot on the italian IG android app]

Comment: The same problem and solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29459942/facebook-security-error-there-are-problems-with-the-security-certificate-for-t/54046269#54046269

Comment: Another "possible" solution for similar issue https://stackoverflow.com/a/63925100/2229148

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I had the error with
`xlplan.com/booking/2/new`

but no error with 
`www.xlplan.com/booking/2/new`

Just adding `www.` helped

Answer (score 0):

[image]

it's directing to the http and not the https link this is my best guess try to add the full link with https on instagram.

Comment: This is the link i have linked to on the facebook shop section: https://gigole-store.com/products/retreat-mid-volume-52-black-pi?taxon_id=109

(To tag products on Instagram you need to create them on the shop section of the connected facebook page)